# Exam class: Indent each question, part and subpart to that of the upper-level indent

Tags: spacing, indentation, paragraphs, exam

I've been working with the class `exam`, and I have been grappling with how I can set the indents for questions and their subparts, and have so far tried every combination of `\setlength{\labelsep}{}`, `\setlength{\labelwidth}{}`, `\setlength{\leftmargin}{}` (`\settowidth{}, too`). I cannot for the life of me figure out something as straightforward as:

1. The question *numbers* (or labels, in this case) have the same indent as the top-level margin; the question content itself (or 'hanging indent') is indented some specified length away from the question. If the question content's paragraph extends over multiple lines, these lines, too, follow the indent of the first line, and *not* the number.
2. If the question has any parts/subparts, the part label indent follows the hanging indent of the question above, and the part content's hanging indent is some specified distance away from the label indent, which in turn is the hanging indent of the question above.
3. Repeat *ad-infinitum* for any more subparts, subsubparts, etc.

A picture speaks a thousand words, and hence, an example using monospace:

```
This is top-level text. 

1.   This is a question. 
2.   This is another, multi-line, multi-paragraph question. 

     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
     consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
     labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost
     rud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo co
     nsequat. 

     Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate veli
     t esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occ
     aecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 
     mollit anim id est laborum.
     (a)   This is a part. 
     (b)   This is another part. 
           (i)    This is a subpart. 
           (ii)   This is another subpart. 
...
```

I know this is borderline heresy at TeX.sx, but I found this positively easy to work out in Word, but completely un-achieveable in \LaTeX.